# Bigquery user statistics from Microstrategy

Tags: google-bigquery, microstrategy

I am using Microstrategy to connect to Bigquery using a service account. I want to collect user level job statistics from MSTR but since I am using a service account, I need a way to track user level job statistics in Bigquery for all the jobs executed via Microstrategy.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Service account to make the requests from Microstrategy, you could look up for all your project Jobs by [listing them](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#listing_jobs_in_a_project) then, by using each Job ID in the list, [gather the information of the job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#viewing_information_about_jobs) as this shows the Email used for the Job ID.

A workaround for this would be also using Stackdriver Logging [advanced filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#getting-started) and use a filter to get the jobs made by the Service Account. For instance:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="<your service account>"
```

Keep in mind this only shows jobs in the last 30 days due to the [Logs retention periods](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas#logs_retention_periods).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But since I am using a service account it is masking the Microstrategy user who ran the report. I need a way to map the Microstrategy user with the bigquery job as right now all the jobs from Microstrategy are masked by the service account.

Comment: For this case, then it won't be a way to track which user is running the reports at the Google Cloud Platform side, since the requests are made by the same Service Account. Nevertheless, you could track the IP who made the request by using the same filter in Stackdriver. This information is in requestMetadata -> callerIP. Otherwise and if all the users have the same IP, you would need to have some kind of login process before your users reach Microstrategy to gather the user activity.

Comment: Ok Thanks F10. Another solution that we thought was creating one service account per user. So if we have 500 users in Microstrategy then we could create 500 service accounts with each service account mapped to one user. I am not sure whether this would work. Your thoughts on this ?

Comment: Yes, that should be an alternative for this. Nevertheless, there's a [limit of 100 Service account per project](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq#what_is_the_maximum_number_of_service_accounts_i_can_have_in_a_project). Thus, you could either contact your account manager if you need more than 100 service account in a project, or you could create 5 projects to create 100 service accounts on each one and monitor the activity on each project.